# What is the "Quick and Dirty" way to transfer WordPress installation?

Tags: installation, migration

I have a site that was made on WordPress back in May by one of my company's non-technical staff. This site is also hosted by WordPress so it's really just a blog at the minute with very little content, however just the other day We have invested in a new host so right now, my objective is to clear out the WordPress site and move my installation of WP to my new host, SiteGround. I have a backup of everything that's important for the WP site so I have no problem with deleting it.

What I'm looking for is a free version of the "Guided Transfer" except, it doesn't matter what content I lose, so long as I can use WordPress on the new server.

Also: I have already configured the new host server with the **domain** name that is currently being used by the WordPress site, could this become an issue?

Comment: You can not move the whole installation from WordPress.com. You can just export the content from there and import into your fresh self-hosted installation.

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the docs: read [Moving a Blog - WordPress.com](http://en.support.wordpress.com/moving-a-blog/) and [Move to Self-Hosted WordPress – Guiding you from WordPress.com to a self-hosted WordPress site.](https://move.wordpress.com/)

You have to do an XML export before you repoint DNS to your new host siteground.

And, you may have to choose new plugins on self-hosted, as well as a different theme, though you can download .com themes here via `svn` and adapt them to self-hosted: http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be too hard. You're using SiteGround, and they use cPanel. cPanel should include Softaculous (SiteGround tutorial [here](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/softaculous.htm)).

Just install Wordpress via Softaculous, which shouldn't take more than a few minutes.

Once you install it and login, go to Tools and import, where (after installing the import plugin) you can import the file you got from your current site after exporting all the content (it's an .xml file, I hope?).

This should transfer pages, posts, media and other data from the site.

Once it's transferred you're ready to shut down the old site.

The question of domain names isn't an issue, since in the end you can only direct a domain to one IP, via your DNS provider. You will need to direct your domain to the IP of your SiteGround host server.

Answer (score -1):

Use akeeba Kickstarter.. 
[See here](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html)
it is a plugin will create package of latest source and it provides one Installation file where you can transfer your WordPress with single click.. all paths will be maintained by the script.. hope it helps..